# Check if dates lie within other dates?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to allow the user to search for a car in the database that 1, isn't already out, and 2, isn't going to be out in the dates they have inputted. So, for example, if a user is looking to rent a car between the 4th and 8th of October it checks for cars that are not already being rented between those dates.

Here is my SQL statement which at the moment produces a missing operator error:

```
With SQLCmd
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "Select * From Tbl_Car Where CarID = @CarIDSearch And Where Out = False And Reserved = False Between PublicDateOfHire and PublicDateOfReturn "
```

Comment: I edited your question as it appears to be about SQL, not VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra where, and you're missing an And and the date you're interested in - e.g.

"Select * From Tbl_Car Where CarID = @CarIDSearch And Out = False And Reserved = False **And @Date** Between PublicDateOfHire and PublicDateOfReturn "